# Why is the create tag and create tag synonym privilege so far apart? And why is tag creation first?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, privileges

Recently I discovered, that I can use a favorite tag like "excel*" to get to all the relevant question - but because there are some additional tags - like [vlookup](/questions/tagged/vlookup) - I still don't get all at once.

So, I thought it might be a good idea to create at least a tag synonym for it, like [excel-vlookup](/questions/tagged/excel-vlookup), but I won't be able to do that for quite a while, due to lack of about 1500 rep.

However, what I (nearly) can do is create new tags, and this boggles me a bit.

*Why does tag creation come before creation of tag synonyms?*

*And secondly, why are these privileges so far apart?!*

IMHO a tag synonym has less impact, than a whole new tag, but can quickly improve usability, and because it is not instantly available, there seems even to be less possibility for abuse or misuse.

Answer (score 4):

> *Why does tag creation come before creation of tag synonyms?*

Because you need to be familiar with the basic concept of tags before you can learn how to work with tag synonyms.

> *And secondly, why are these privileges so far apart?!*

Tag synonym relationships can be created between two existing tags (tags that are being used with questions). This can have drastic effects on how a question is tagged, because you're essentially remapping one tag to another on *all* questions with that tag.

Granted, tag synonyms go through a voting process before being approved and taking effect, plus it is reversible *provided the tags haven't been merged by a moderator*, but we don't really want users to be messing around with such large-scale issues until they're very familiar with the site and its use of tags.

You should realize, though, that the gap between creating tag synonyms and creating tags is the same as creating tags and retagging with existing tags (1000 rep difference).

Comment: what about synonyms that are created, hence did not exist before as tags? wouldn't it be a good thing, to create tags including some synonyms for them - as long as those don't exist as tags already? Or to create synonyms, as long as they don't already exist as tags? I very much understand the concerns about merging existing, in use tags - but that is not what I had in mind.

Comment: oh, thanks for the hint with the rep difference - had that wrong - and your explaination of the current differences. This all makes more sense now. However, I would be interested in your/the general thought on my suggestion for "newly created synonyms".